# Tamaño de letra en HTML

Tags: html, css

Tengo el siguiente codigo:

```html
<a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a>
```

Necesito darle tamaño a la letra en HTML.

Comment: La pregunta es un poco básica, hay miles de resultados en google sobre el tema ¿Hay algo diferente a los resultados de búsqueda que quieres lograr?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplemente cambia su tamaño usando el atributo [**font-size**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_font.asp) de css:

```
<a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url" style="font-size: 2.5em">Premio</a>
```

A este atributo le puedes pasar tanto un tamaño de fuente en:

- **pixeles**: `font-size: 20px`
- **porcentajes**: `font-size: 150%`
- **unidades em** (que son las más recomendadas): `font-size: 2.5em`
- o [valores predefinidos](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_font_font-size.asp): `font-size: large`

---

*Ejemplo con em*

```html
<a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url" style="font-size: 2.5em">Premio</a>
```

Answer (score 3):

Una opcion es usar h1, h2, h3...

```html
<h1><a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a></h1>
<h2><a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a></h2>
<h3><a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a></h3>
<h4><a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a></h4>
<h5><a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a></h5>
```

Comment: Esto es un error, las etiquetas de HTML (incluidas las etiquetas h1, h2, h3...) existen para aportar semántica a la página. No se deben utilizar para aplicar estilos solo porque cada navegador web disponga de estilos por defecto que vayan a aplicarse a las mismas. Puedes consultar la finalidad de cada etiqueta en https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element En su lugar deben aplicarse estilos (CSS). Recomiendo encarecidamente la lectura del siguiente artículo de Google: https://developers.google.com/style/semantic-tagging

Comment: @RobertoPintosLópez tienes razon, lo especificare tu observacion en mi respuesta

Answer (score 1):

Puedes darle el tamaño a través de CSS, directamente en la etiqueta agregandole el atributo "font-size: 12px" por ejemplo, o en unidades "em" <- Esta última permite que el tamaño sea adaptable según condiciones previas. si lo vas a hacer directamente en HTML el resultado sería:

```
<a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url" style= "font-sixe: 12px">Premio</a> ó
<a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url" style= "font-sixe: 2em">Premio</a>
```

Si lo haces por CSS podría ser:

```
<a href="Campaña.xlsx" id="url">Premio</a>
```

#url a {
        font-size: 12px;
   }